# ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am trying to build a.NET project that was built on 7 using Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines. I am getting this error.

```
 In Build Part getting this errors ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1.
```

```
##[error] The Dotnet command failed with a non-zero exit code on the following projects: [ 'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API'
```

When I enabled system.debug to true, I got to know there was a version error. It was trying to build on.NET 5.x, where this project needed to build on 7.x. So again, I added PerformMultilookup to true in the.NET Core installation for Microsoft Hosted Agents. Now it's installing the 7.x version, but it's still trying to build it with the 5.x version. So again, in the Microsoft article, I found need to use global.json, so I enabled it again, but global.json was not there in the project. So without global.json facing a build issue, is global.json needed to build this project? If yes, then I need to ask my developer to write this and will try, but before that, any suggestions without global.json will help me to save my time, and is there any way please help on this? here i am adding debug logs for your reference .

```
##[debug]pattern: 'src/Integrations.Services.Configuration.API'
##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API'
##[debug]statOnly: 'true'
##[debug]found 1 paths
##[debug]applying include pattern
##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'D:\a\1\s\src/Integrations.Services.Configuration.API'
##[debug]1 matches
##[debug]1 final results
##[debug]which 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]found: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: build
##[debug]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: D:\a\1\s\src\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API
##[debug]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: -dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
##[debug]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe arg: --project $ (BuildConfiguration)
##[debug]exec tool: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   build
##[debug]   D:\a\1\s\src\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API
##[debug]   -dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
##[debug]   --project
##[debug]   $
##[debug]   (BuildConfiguration)
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build D:\a\1\s\src\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API "-dl:CentralLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"*ForwardingLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"" --project $ (BuildConfiguration)
MSBuild version 17.7.4+3ebbd7c49 for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
    Full command line: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary D:\a\1\s\src\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API -dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.235.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" --project $ (BuildConfiguration) -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\dotnet.dll'
  Switches appended by response files:
Switch: --project

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ 'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API' ]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ 'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API' ]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ 'D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\Integrations.Services.Configuration.API' ]
Finishing: Build
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the debug log you shared, it seems that there are some problems with your parameters. `--project $ (BuildConfiguration)`

Below is my yaml file, which works fine. You can refer to it.

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```